# how to use maven to automatically install sigar binaries java path

Tags: java, maven, sigar

I'm wondering if there was a way to get the sigar compiled binaries ie. `libsigar-universal-macosx.dylib` etc.. using maven. i know that i can just manually add it but I wish to automate the deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In maven there are lot of way to arrange your build

Consider the following options:

- Quick and dirty: Make dependency of scope 'system' put the library in the predefined place and build. 
  Read about the system scope [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- Much better approach although requires more work: create a maven repository with the thirdparty jars that you don't have in repo 1. Although you can use http server like apache and provide an http based access to such a repository, I would recommend you to use the proxy that was build exactly for this purpose. Consider to use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home) for this.
  Then configure these repositories in the maven installation (all the sigar jars will be managed by this repository) and build your project.

Hope this helps